# rails rendering layout on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

With my controller "formulaire"  when I'm validating my datas on "Create" and that I have errors on my validation. Rails re-render the Form with the "NEw" action but it doens't render the layout that I have specified on "New"...

```
# GET /formulaires/new
  def new
    @formulaire = Formulaire.new
    render layout: "main"
  end

  # GET /formulaires/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /formulaires
  # POST /formulaires.json
  def create
    @formulaire = Formulaire.new(formulaire_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @formulaire.save
        format.html { redirect_to @formulaire, notice: 'Formulaire was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @formulaire }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @formulaire.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /formulaires/1
  # PATCH/PUT /formulaires/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @formulaire.update(formulaire_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @formulaire, notice: 'Formulaire was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @formulaire.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED: Add to your controller before actions:

```
layout :resolve_layout
```

And in the end of the controller:

```
protected

def resolve_layout
  case action_name
  when 'new', 'create'
    'main'
  else
    'application'
  end
end
```